# Steam complains it's missing 32-bit libc.so.6

Tags: apt, package-management, steam

I've downloaded Steam already but it gives me an error when I try to run it: "You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6". So I tried to download it and typed `sudo apt-get install libc-i386` but it just gave me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libc-i386
```

I have tried `sudo apt-get update` then running `sudo apt-get install libc-i386` but it just gave me the same error code again. Any help? Also, I've only had this running for a few hours so I don't know much about it.

Sorry I ran the second one and it gave me a lot of links which it won't let me add to this edit but the last part said

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu version do you have? libc-i386 does exist. As for my answer, remove the architecture (if the earlier command said it had been added) so that your system stays the way it was. `dpkg --remove-architecture i386`

Comment: i typed "lsb_release -a" as google told me to do and I got "No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial"

Comment: i just tried to remove the architecture but it gave me this: "dpkg: error: unable to create new file '/var/lib/dpkg/arch-new': Permission denied"

Comment: The package administration tasks are usually run with `sudo`. I should've added it.

Comment: okay i just ran it and deleted it

Comment: what shoud i do now

Comment: You should use the package name libc6-i386 to install.

Answer (score 0):

You could download the package directly:

```
$ wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6-i386_2.23-0ubuntu10_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i libc6-i386_2.23-0ubuntu10_amd64.deb
```

If you don't have `wget`, you can visit the link with your browser and download the file. Then run the command with the path to it (it could something like /home/YOUR_USER/Downloads).